# React-native is not able to render any data,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rendering, server-side

i am working to set up my environment  for react native.

Things seemed to be working fine unless i started the server. Where react-native is not able to render anything . It renders files as plain text even html files.

```
    **
   * Sample React Native App
   * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
   *
  * @format
  * @flow
  */

import React, {Component} from 'react';    
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';


 const instructions = Platform.select({
 ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
 android:
 'ctrl+R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
 });

 type Props  = {};
 export default class App extends Component<Props> {
 render() {
     return (..............
```

##########################################################

#

```
          **Below is the output in browser tab**
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native! Although    
       </Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit 
   App.js</Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Output in the browser tab? Are you checking it on a web browser? `react-native` is meant to be used for standalone mobile apps, not web... There's an implementation of it `react-native-web` for web, but the go to is isually plain `react.js`... I believe you missunderstood the purpose of `react-native`, check the tutorial on their webpage to check how to use it with Android or iOS.

Comment: Right sir .... actually earlier when I was trying with expo client the same was working with me . So I expected it might as well... BTW thanks .  But still I can't find out from where local host is displaying that file . Because I am not able to locate any such file.

Comment: Expo client give you options to open an Android simulator (and iOS simulator if you are using MacOS). If you don't have a simulator or physical device, you'll not be able to see the result you expect, there's no "file" until you bundle it.

Comment: Thank you sir for clarification . Thanks a lot .